# How can I pass variables to a JQuery definition / method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery to create a Popup Window (UI). If I use the code below, I just have a hadcoded height of 600px. Is there a way, how I can pass a variable to the height parameter?

```
myFrame.dialog({
    title: "Foto-Upload",
    width: 570,
    height: 600,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {

                 "Schließen": function() {
                     $(this).dialog("close");
                 }
    },
    closeOnEscape: true,
    resizable: false
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get or set the width option, after init.

```
// get the width
var width = myFrame.dialog( "option", "width" );

// set the width
myFrame.dialog( "option", "width", 460 );
```

RTM: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-width

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
width: document.getElementById('image-width')
```

wherein image-width is

```
<input type="text" name="image-width" id="image-width">
```

Answer (score -1):

It basically already is a "parameter" taken by the dialog "function-object".

But if it was within another function you could pass it a variable too, like the following fiddle:

```
var _myHeight = 300;

setIt(_myHeight);

function setIt(_h) {
    $("#dialog").dialog({height: _h });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tommyAwesome/NmfrP/

It would however be better to use the parameter of the dialog function. (since your going to have to use it anyways.)